# "Roll Over" in the Song Roll Over Beethoven

Tags: phrase-meaning

There is a famous Chuck Berry song titled [*Roll Over Beethoven*](https://genius.com/Chuck-berry-roll-over-beethoven-lyrics). The overall meaning was telling a DJ to stop playing classical music and play rock and roll. But when I looked up for the [definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/roll-over) of the phrase "roll over", I can't find a meaning suitable for here. Can you explain what does "roll over" mean here?

Comment: I'm so old I remember when the Beatles released the song. At the time I interpreted it to mean "Move out of the way, you've had your time, you've been replaced."

Comment: (Though younger) I agree with the comment above. It think it simply means 'step aside', not 'turn in your grave', as suggested by Wikipedia. The song was written and recorded in 1956, when, certainly the phrase 'to turn in one's grave' existed, but was little used.

Comment: @Strawberry: Is your comment suggesting that the expression _to turn in one's grave_ wasn't used much _anymore_ in 1956, or that it wasn't used _yet_?

Comment: @Schmuddi - FWIW, the usual phrase is *turning in [his/her/their/the] grave* or *spinning in [his/her/their/the] grave*. "Rolling over" in [his/her/their/the] grave is more modern. Ngrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rolling+over+in+%2A+grave%2Cspinning+in+%2A+grave%2Cturning+in+%2A+grave&corpus=26&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Can you post an answer?

Comment: We Brits tend to say "turn in one's grave". There is the old joke about the woman who dies, and upon reaching heaven, wishes to be reunited with her husband, who predeceased her. His name is John Smith. Saint Peter says 'Do you know how many of those we have here? We would locate him if you could remember his last words'. The woman says 'He said, "If you're unfaithful to my memory, I'll turn in my grave"'. 'Ah!, says Saint Peter! '_Turbine_ John Smith'.

Comment: Esquire magazine had a cover with the words "Roll over Elvis" to announce a feature about Jim Morrison. The New York Times had a headline saying that too, in 1996, above an article about celebrities on postage stamps. The phrase is pretty widespread in fact.

Comment: It's hard to imagine using "roll over" instead of "move over" (which would have scanned just as well and seems more idiomatic to me). But maybe the usage was different back then.

Comment: @user3067860: “Roll over” is a much stronger-sounding start to the line than  “Move over” would be (because of the relative hardness of the R and M sounds)

Comment: it's a [train, according to ELO](https://genius.com/Electric-light-orchestra-rock-and-roll-is-king-lyrics) (who also covered Chuck Berry's masterpiece):   It rolls like a train that's comin' on down the track ♫ She rolled over Beethoven and she gave Tchaikovsky back

Comment: Like some comments above, I always assumed that it meant that Rock & Roll would make Beethoven [turn over in his grave](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn-over-in-your-grave). I have never even imagined that it could possibly have any other meaning.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll_Over_Beethoven)

> The lyric "roll over Beethoven and tell Tchaikovsky the news" refers to how classical composers would **roll over in their graves** upon hearing that classical music had given way to rock and roll.

[further details:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_in_one%27s_grave)

> (Enough to make one) "turn in one's grave" is an idiom to describe an extreme level of shock or an intense level of surprise and is expressed as the vicarious sentiment of a deceased person. ... Other forms or "fanciful variants" of this idiom includes: "Roll over in one's grave"

Comment: Due respect to the random Wikipedia editor, I don't buy it. Note that the claim is unsourced. I find Michael Harvey's "get out of the way" [interpretation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/261411/roll-over-in-the-song-roll-over-beethoven#comment489877_261411) much more believable. Also, "rolling over" in the grave is a relatively modern modification of earlier phrases; [more here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/261411/roll-over-in-the-song-roll-over-beethoven#comment490001_261411).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The part "and tell Tchaikovsky the news" is a, well, dead giveaway that he's to roll over in his grave, isn't it? As is often the case with natural language the "make space" meaning admittedly  may also hang in the air; since it's *Rock'n'**Roll*** there may also be a third meaning in the background: Mr. Beethoven was a rebel at his time as well and may not be able to keep his feet still when he hears Chuck Berry! *[Sorry, I wanted to add the third meaning and had to rewrite the comment, now your answer is above it]*

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica - :-) It isn't to me, no. I'd really want sources to back it (or any other interpretation) up before stating something definitively as the Wikipedia article does. I think the Tchaikovsky thing (which isn't always the next line) is just a follow-on to broaden it to classical music in general. But people should enjoy whatever interpretation they like. :-)

Comment: Chuck Berry's own words do not back it up: "In fact most of the words were aimed at Lucy instead of the Maestro Ludwig Van Beethoven."  Lucy was his elder sister, and he's telling her and her music to _move out of the way_ because she "would monopolize the piano at home during our youthful school years" playing classical music.

Comment: @JdeBP - If you have a citation for that, it would make a good answer, or a good supporting citation for [chasly's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/261481/8743).

Comment: Does not make sense because classical music has *not yet* given way to rock'n'roll - the narrator is writing a letter petitioning the radio DJ.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The 1991 book Heavy Metal: A Cultural Society also says "Here AC/DC acknowledges one of the founders of rock and roll , Chuck Berry , who in his 1955 song 'Roll Over Beethoven' exhorts Beethoven to roll over in his grave and tell Tchaikovsky the good news that rock and roll has been born ."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://bit.ly/2EOe2mM

Comment: @DavePhD - That again begs the question of what's the source of that information? Who's the author's source? :-)

Comment: @Strawberry - Nice link!!

Answer (score 27):

I agree with the comment by @Michael Harvey although I can't quote a source.

For me, "roll over" means "move over" or "move out of the way"

**There's an old children's rhyme**

> There were ten in a bed and the little one said
>
> "Roll over, roll over"
>
> So they all rolled over and one fell out
>
> There were nine in a bed and the little one said
>
> "Roll over, roll over"
>
> So they all rolled over and one fell out
>
> There were eight in a bed and the little one said
>
> "Roll over, roll over"
>
> So they all rolled over and one fell out
>
> http://www.lyricsondemand.com/miscellaneouslyrics/childrenslyrics/rolloverlyrics.html

Comment: Supported by this dictionary entry: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/roll-over#:~:text=3.-,phrasal%20verb,or%20attacked%20by%20the%20I.R.S. and as a native speaker (in England) I have used the phrase with this meaning, and heard it used that way many times.

Answer (score 1):

Rolling over is something that a dog does to acknowledge domination by another dog. This is likely to mean the same. Beethoven, roll over on your back, and acknowledge the dominance of Rock’n’Roll.

Answer (score 1):

It seems short for "Roll over and play dead", meaning to submit or comply without any action, resistance, or protest. It is similar to what animals do when feigning death when faced with some predators. As explained [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/roll+over+and+play+dead).

Answer (score 0):

"Roll over" simply means to give way to pressure.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/roll-over

In this context Chuck Berry is telling classical composers (Beethoven, Tchaikovsky, etc) to "give way, rock and roll is here".

There could be a "roll over in his grave" interpretation (the normal terminology is "*turn* in his grave" though), but without a reference to Berry's intent, the standard definition seems to be the simplest explanation.